# Find the discontinuous point of $f$, where $ f(x)=\lim_{a\to x}\bigg(\frac{\sin a}{\sin x}\bigg)^{\frac{x}{\sin a-\sin x}}. $

Tags: analysis

> Find the discontinuous point of $f$, where 
>   $$
> f(x)=\lim_{a\to x}\bigg(\frac{\sin a}{\sin x}\bigg)^{\frac{x}{\sin a-\sin x}}.
> $$

If $\sin x\ne0$, we have $f(x)=e^{\frac{x}{\sin x}}$. But how to evaluate when $\sin x=0$, since $f(x)$ seems to be nonsense.

Comment: If $f$ is simply undefined when $\sin x = 0$, then points such that $\sin x = 0$ will be points of discontinuity. I think instead you're meant to assume that $f$ is the continuous extension of $e^{\frac{x}{\sin x}}$. As you may know $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}  = 1$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = e^1 = e$. Meanwhile, if $x = n\pi$ with $n \neq 0$, then $\lim_{a \to x} \frac{a}{\sin a}$ does not exist. Thus the discontinuities of $f$ are the points $x = n\pi$ with $n \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{a \rightarrow x} \left(\frac{\sin a}{\sin x} \right)^{\frac{x}{\sin a-\sin x}}= \lim_{a \rightarrow x}\left( \left( 1+\frac{\sin a- \sin x}{\sin x} \right)^{\frac{\sin x}{\sin a- \sin x}}\right)^{\frac{x}{\sin x}} =\exp[{\frac{x}{\sin x}}].$$

Here we have used $\lim_{\rightarrow 0}(1+z)^{1/z}=e.$
Hence, $f(x)=e^{x/\sin x}$ is dis-continuous at $x=n \pi, n=1,2,3,...$.